# touchでmkdir -pも行いたい

Tags: linux

touchでディレクトリをほってファイルを作成することは出来ますか?

`/var/www/html/index.html`を作りたい時に`/var/www/`までしかディレクトリがない場合にいちいちディレクトリを作るのがめんどくさいです。

1回のコマンドで簡単に済ませる方法があれば教えて下さいな

Answer (score 11):

`install -D /dev/null /var/www/html/index.html`

---

### 追記: このコマンドは既にあるファイルを上書きします(!)

`--backup`オプションで退避させる事もできますが、touchと同じ効果を期待するなら他の回答のように `mkdir` と `touch` を組み合わせたほうが良いと思います。

#### 本当に欲しかったもの

`sh -c 'mkdir -p "$(dirname "$0")" && touch "$0"' /var/www/html/index.html`

#### 解説

- `sh -c <command> <args...>`
  既存のセッションに非ログイン/非インタラクティブなshのプロセスを作成し、`<command>`を実行します。 /bin/sh は Ubuntu で dash 、 CentOS だと bash になりますので、コマンドは bourne-shell で書くのが良いかと思います。外側の `<args...>` はそれぞれ `<command>` 中の `$0`, `$1` ... に代入されます。
- `dirname <arg>`
  `<arg>` に渡された文字列をファイルパスとしてそのディレクトリを参照します。 `<arg>` には空白やグロブ(`*`等)が含まれる可能性があるため、ダブルクォートで括ります。
- `$(<command>)`
  `<command>`を実行し、その標準出力を文字列とします。古いbourne-shellではバッククォートで書く必要がありましたが、昨今はPOSIXに準拠したシェルであれば基本的に広く使えると考えてかまわないでしょう。バッククォートでも書けなくはないですが、内側の `"` をエスケープする必要があります。
- `mkdir -p <arg>`
  ご存知の通りです。 `<arg>`に空白が含まれる可能性があるのでダブルクォートでくくります。
- `&&`
  `mkdir` が失敗した時に `touch` が実行されてしまわないよう短絡評価にします。コマンド実行前に `/var/www/html/index.html/` という **ディレクトリ** が存在した場合、 `mkdir -p` は失敗するでしょう。
- `touch "$0"`
  shコマンドで渡されていた引数で `touch` します。

Comment: このコマンドは既にファイルがあるときに破壊してしまうという点で `touch` とは挙動が異なるわけですが、危険すぎません？

Comment: @774RR 「/var/www/までしかディレクトリがない場合」と「1回のコマンドで」が前提条件として頭にこびりついてました。backupオプションもありますがtouch代わり使うならセオリー通りmkdir && touchでしょうね。回答に修正を追加しておきます。

Answer (score 1):

こんなんでいかがですか。.bashrcとかに入れてください

```
dirtouch() {
    mkdir -p "$(dirname $1)"
    touch "$1"
}
alias touch=dirtouch
```

編集: スペース対策のクォート

Answer (score 1):

以下にすれば複数のパスに対応できます。
`dirtouch test/{a,b}.txt`でも使える。

```sh
dirtouch() {
    for i in "$@"
    do
        mkdir -p $(dirname "$i")
        touch "$i"
    done
}
```

(アカウントの信用度が低いので別コメントとして回答)

Comment: 一行余計ですね。シェルスクリプトに疎いもので。
ダブルクオートもいらないみたいでした。
修正しときました。

Comment: ダブルクォートがないと、空白を含む場合に誤作動します。

Comment: 空白がある場合、for i in $@で別要素としてイテレーションされるので、ダブルクオートなくてもいいのではと思うので外してみました。が、シェルスクリプト詳しくないので、変なバグ防ぐためにダブルクオート合ったほうがいいですね。

Comment: ちなみに、`for NAME [in WORDS ... ] ; do COMMANDS; done ... If "in WORDS ...;" is not present, then 'in "$@"' is assumed.` ですので、`for i;do ... done` とすることもできます。

Answer (score 1):

[kebabu_wrap](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/36129/kazuhiro-sakurayama)さんの[回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/59582/25936)の発展形です。
手元では`-h`とか`--date`などの引数を使うのでそれらを無視するようにしました。

```sh
touch () {
    for arg in "$@"; do
        case "$arg" in
            -d|-r|-t) next="skip"; continue ;;
                  -*) continue ;;
                   *) test "$next" = "skip" && { unset next; continue; } ;;
        esac
        mkdir --parent "$(dirname "$arg")"
    done
    command -p touch "$@"
}
```